# Can we ensure that Class * parameter is filled only with a subclass of NSManagedObject?

Tags: objective-c

I have this method:

```
@implementation NSObject (defaultSelector)
+(NSDictionary *) idSelectorDictionary
{
    if (_idSelectors==nil)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * IDSelectors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([DistanceGrouping class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Description));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Business class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(ID));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Tag class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Name));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Image class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(URL));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Alias class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(stringAlias));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([City class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Name));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Country class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Name));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([District class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(ID));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Phone class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(thePhone));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([URL class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Name));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([KeyPhrase class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(thekeyword));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([PlaceCache class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Text));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([BGCatalogData class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(id));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([CategoryNearby class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(imageNamed));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([Review class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(ID));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([KeyPhrase class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(thekeyword));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([AutoCompleteEntry class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(idOfEntries));
        IDSelectors[NSStringFromClass([CDParent class])]=NSStringFromSelector(@selector(strParentId));
        _idSelectors = IDSelectors;
    }
    return _idSelectors;
}
```

That is a category of NSObject. Why NSObject? Actually I want that to be a category of NSManagedObject.

However if I do that, these code won't work:

```
+(void) debuggingToolsShowObjectsWithThisIDs: (NSArray *) localObjectIDs forClass: (Class) class
...
    NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K in %@",class.defaultSelector,localObjectIDs];
```

I got this error:

> /business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler.m:286:71: Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'Class' (aka 'Class *') to C pointer type 'struct objc_class *' requires a bridged cast

Can I change (Class) to (NSManagedObjectSubclass) or something?